# SASS change nested elements class naming style

Tags: css, sass, smacss

I'd like to use SMACSS naming system with SASS.
Expect following SASS code:

```
nav
  ul
    margin: 0
    padding: 0
    list-style: none
```

as output i'll get

```
nav ul {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  list-style: none;
}
```

but according to the SMACSS methodology class naming should looks like this:

```
nav-ul {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  list-style: none;
}
```

Could you please advice how to change class naming style in SASS to reach this goal?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can write it like this:

```
nav
  &-ul
    margin: 0
    padding: 0
    list-style: none
```

result:

```
nav-ul {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  list-style: none;
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! works great! But is there any way to change compile configuration to replace standard naming with what have you provided?

Comment: Sadly i just don't know. But i think it would not always be helpful to have this syntax. For example for selectors like `ul > li`. Maybe someone with more insight in SMACSS can provide some information on that.